# Set Accepts in HTTP Download Request Header

Tags: wcf, wcf-web-api

I have a WCF Web Api endpoint that returns an invoice: http://localhost/api/invoice/23

The format it returns is that of the accepts header in the request. If the Javascript wants JSON or XML then it just sets this in the accept header. This is how WCF Web Api seems to work. I've added a PDF formatter to invoice so that when asking for application/pdf it will get a rendered pdf file stream back with the appropriate MIME type. This works fine and I can test it in fiddler.

I need the user to click something in the browser to start the PDF download and pop up the open/save dialog. I don't know how to do this and set the accept header of the request. Static links or window.location in javascript won't work because it doesn't let me set the header. AJAX request won't work because although I can set the header, it expects text back and it won't show as a download in the browser.

I'm not sure how I can do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just dynamically create a form in JavaScript and ask it to start in a new tab. That should give you what you want.

```
function SubmitRequest() 
{
        var myForm = document.createElement("form");
        myForm.method = "post";
        myForm.action = "url here"
        var myInput = document.createElement("input");
        myInput.setAttribute("name", "json");
        myForm.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
        myInput.setAttribute("value", "Your value here");
        myForm.appendChild(myInput);
        document.body.appendChild(myForm);
        myForm.submit();
        document.body.removeChild(myForm);
    }
```

Comment: Why would he want to do a POST?

Comment: This was almost exactly what I was after, only changing the method to a GET and adding an accept header into the accept attribute on the form. However it turns out that no browsers support the accept header when specified in the form. Oh Darn

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add an A tag in your page with a link to `http://localhost/api/invoice/23.pdf` and then use the AddUriPathExtensionMapping on your formatter to have it generate the accept header automatically from the path extension on the URI.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with .extension. It kept saying endpoint not found so wouldn't get to any formatters. I found in the sample code a message handler that allowed me to convert invoice/23/pdf into the appropriate accept header, which then allowed my pdf formatter to do it's work and leaving the invoice service itself completely oblivious to the goings on. So thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to give it a go.  It's supposed to work with .extension