# WCF Webapi UriTemplate with file extension works local but not on IIS7

Tags: iis-7, wcf-web-api

I have a WCF WebApi Rest service that has the following endpoints:

```cs
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}")]
```

and

```cs
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}.pdf")]
```

The first endpoint returns JSON and the second endpoint returns a pdf.  Both of these endpoints work in my local environment, but the pdf endpoint returns a `404` on the server running IIS7.

Is there some sort of setup IIS7 that is needed in order for the route to get executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem.  It is a simple web.config addition:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
      <add name="PDFHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*.pdf" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to add .pdf to the MIME TYPE's in IIS

try adding file extension .PDF with a type of application/octet-stream

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

**UPDATE**

To return a dynamically generated PDF directly using something like itextsharp:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetPDF/{id}")]        
public void GetPDF(int id)
        {
        Invoice i = InvoiceData.GetInvoiceByID(id);
        MyApp.Data.Export.PDF pdf = new MyApp.Data.Export.PDF();
        byte[] data = pdf.generatePDFBytes(id);

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + i.InvoiceNumber + ".pdf" + "\"");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(data.ToArray());
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: This mime type is setup - I think the problem has to do with IIS trying to serve up a static file instead of routing the request.

Comment: Ya, you might be right. Are you able to just change the route to not use the extension and pass the parameter in the path like `[WebGet(UriTemplate = "{id}/pdf")]`?

Comment: I'm actually trying to implement this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7347522/1330215) so that I can directly link to a dynamically generated pdf (ex:  <a href="http://api.company.com/invoices/12345.pdf">Your Invoice</a>).

Comment: I've done something similar where I created a function to return the dynamically generated PDF as the server response so that it could be opened or downloaded directly. I've modified the above answer to show an example of that function.

Comment: Thanks for the update Matt. Generating the pdf isn't an issue for me - it's actually working locally and returns a beautiful pdf. :)  The problem happens when I make the same request on the server and instead of executing the route, it returns a 404.